# CoreData fetch by to many relationship property

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have this structure -
Question <- One To Many-> AnswerAttempt

Every answer attempt has creation date property

Now lets say that I need to fetch the latest 100 AnswerAttempts but enforce that their question should be unique.

Any way to do this in one request?

Thanks
Shani

Comment: Does `predicateWithBlock` counts as one request?

Comment: No, but thanks for trying

Comment: what is Question primary key?

Comment: id but why is that relevant ?

Comment: @shannoga you need to fech 100 answer with  unique  question ?

Comment: @shannoga what happen ?

Comment: @balkaransingh 100 latest answers but all with unique questions